# Runtime Error in VBA when using SaveCopyAs

Tags: excel, vba

I just started on a new project and was asked to put together a quick and easy way to save multiple order reports from one document. Everything was working great until I reached the point of saving the information on a new workbook. It creates the folders requested, but I receive [this runtime error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SebOO.png) when reaching the .SaveCopyAs line. Any help would be appreciated!

```
Dim path_ As String
    path_ = Workbooks("Order Reporting.xlsm").Worksheets("Start").Range("B14").Value & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Start").Range("K14")

' In this instance: C:\Users\claska\OneDrive\Procurement\RSCS Open Order Reports\HUT

Dim name_ As String
    name_ = Workbooks("Order Reporting.xlsm").Worksheets("Start").Range("K14") & " Open Orders " & Date & ".xlsx"
        
' If not folder, create folder

    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If Not .FolderExists(path_) Then .CreateFolder path_
    End With
        
'Save Sheet to new workbook
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Open Orders").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=path_ & "\" & name_
ActiveWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=False
```

Comment: Are slashes (_"/"_) allowed in file and folder names?

Comment: No, but the backslashes ("\") are used in the directory for the file location

Comment: You may need to use `SaveAs` instead of `SaveCopyAs`

Comment: Try `Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")` in the file name instead of just `Date`

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked that. Thank you!